# Cannot share folder or copy paste between Windows host and Ubuntu guest on Virtual Box

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm using Virtual Box with a 64-bit Windows 10 host and a 64-bit Ubuntu guest.
The Virtual Box download and install are fresh from last week.

**My problem is : I cannot seem to find a way to share files between the host and the guest.**

I tried to enable a shared folder but the host does not see the guest on the network, so I could not achieve that. I tried to fix this problem with a bridge connexion but I was not enough.

Then I tried to simply enable the bidirectional copy-paste and drag-and-drop between the host and the guest. But that does not work either.

I installed and re-installed a dozen of times the Guest Additions CD on my guest, with system reboots, but it was not enough.

*I honestly have no clue about what to do. I never used a virtual machine or Linux before. Please feel free to ask for any configuration information if you need it to help me fix this problem.*

Comment: Did you try and install virtual box extension package?

Comment: @NiklasRosencrantz No I did not before. Now it's done and nothing has changed... I even re-installed the Guest Additions after that and restarted the VM just in case, but no luck.